is it possible to retain the dns name of the url from where we are redirecting to another url using rewrite rule in apache 2.4.51?
I am using a configuration something like  below:
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName test.na.xyz.com

I have the document root and the certs ,keys etc set in this virtual host.
My question is , lets say i am rewriting using based on the condition /postResponse to lets say https://www.efg.com/xyz  as below:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/postResponse$
RewriteRule ^/postResponse$ https://www.efg.com/xyz

Can i retain the host name mentioned in the server name parameter ?
After the redirect to the mentioned url , I want it to look something like  :
https://test.na.xyz.com/xyz  but still be the url that i am rewriting it to that is shown on the browser  based on the condition after redirect.
Is this possible using rewriteRule's in apache or is the proxypreservehost using proxy passes the only way to retain the hostname?

You mean reverse proxy instead of redirection.

Short answer, no.
But depending on www.efg.com is configured you could make it look as if you did by redirecting to a page on test.na.xyz.com with a full window iframe.
